# Job sites for applied/interdisciplinary jobs in Mathematics?

Tags: job, job-search, mathematics

I was wondering whether there're job sites that post jobs in applied/interdisciplinary mathematics, more specially, say postdocs or higher positions in mathematics and medical imaging, mathematics and computer vision. I'm aware of mostly all the popular job sites, mathjobs, euro math jobs, jobs.ac.uk, nordic math jobs etc etc, but most of the jobs there are of 'pure' nature, with very few for applied/interdisciplinary. I find it a little strange, since it seems (I might be mistaken) that they've more funding in the interdisciplinary areas, which should mean they'd have more available jobs too, but I don't see any!

For my particular case, I'm trying to find postdoctoral position in mathematical imaging problems, which would use significant amount of conformal/quasiconformal mappings, Riemann surfaces, differential geometry etc. I guess looking into individual group's webpage is an option, but that's just too much work, since you've to google them first, then see what groups actually work in your areas, then look at their sites etc. But if there's an webpage containing all the information, that'll be much better!

So, if you know any such website for the above (for Europe and the US), I'd appreciate if you could pass them onto me. Thanks! And sorry for having sounded so shameless about the funding comparison.

Comment: Sounds like a computer science problem to me -- have you tried computer science jobs websites?

Comment: I will try, thank you. Actually, it also requires a lot of pure math, depending on what kind of problem one's working on.

Answer (score 2):

I know of:

- The [SIAM Job board](http://jobs.siam.org/jobseeker/search/results/)
- The [NA-Digest list](http://www.netlib.org/na-digest-html/), ostensibly restricted to numerical analysis but in practice lists jobs in a wide range of math-related subjects