# Where can one find jobs where companies hire mathematicians where they can do (not necessarily mainstream) research?

Tags: job-search, mathematics, industry

Several companies (google, IBM etc.) are known to hire mathematicians with advanced degrees (Ph.D. and so) to work in different sectors. Many such jobs are also research jobs, if not all. But I almost never find any such job advertisements in the standard mathjob sites I know of, including mathjobs.org, euro-math-soc.eu/jobs, nordic math jobs etc. Where can I find these type of job advertisements?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about jobs outside academia. It also has too many possible answers, so is too broad.

Comment: I'd agree that it's somewhat outside academia, although not quite because many people who continue in academia for a really long tile (like me) are also exploring options outside academia.

Comment: Is this in reference to **research** jobs in industry for mathematicians? If so, it may be on-topic, as this is a site for *anyone in or interested in research-related or research-adjacent fields*.

Comment: Secondly, possibility of too many answers is highly doubtful, because it's specified to industry jobs for Ph.D. math holders, which is specific enough.

Comment: yes mostly research jobs I've meant, question edited.

Comment: I can't think of a better SE than here; [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) would surely vote to close this.

Comment: Related-but-no-duplicate: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/pure-math-phd-careers/ I agree with @BenWebster's comment there, on why **not** to close such a question: *What else you might do with a graduate degree is obviously of interest to academics.*

Comment: "Many such jobs are also research jobs" - what's your source? Is "many" 5%, 10%, 80%? I have a little experience in one of the larger European software companies, and most mathematicians here do software development or QA, so I'd tend to the "5%" range above. See my answer here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/pure-math-phd-careers/ Being a mathematician is certainly not a problem in such a job, but a CS or physics guy would fit in just as well. This is why such jobs are rarely posted on sites that cater primarily to mathematicians.

Comment: Perhaps the OP has in mind an outfit like Microsoft Research, which hires real research mathematicians to do real mathematics research. I think this question is on topic and likely answerable.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with @Nate... just because academic research is not being conducted in a university doesn't mean it's not academia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Industrial jobs are announced on different basis than academic ones. Typically, there is no a position to be filled. Rather (larger companies) are hiring on semi-continuous basis, and assign people to groups internally.

Sometimes there are more research-oriented openings, for example [Facebook: Data Scientist, Product Science](https://www.facebook.com/careers/department?dept=engineering&req=a0IA000000CzAdDMAV). Just bear in mind it is mostly very applied science, and in fields like Machine Learning, Statistics, maybe some Graph Theory or Cryptography.

So look at big companies (smaller companies may not have such specialized positions or money to invest in long-term development) in technology (Google, Microsoft, Facebook, ...) and their openings. When it comes to direct positions, usually you can choose only *after* interviews (you rarely see research positions being on the front page).

If it is nice research, or building webpages in a disguise, the only way is to ask people working at the company. Or look at CVs of your colleagues in your field who did internships in these companies (especially ones that you know are pure mathematicians or computer scientists).